# does cassandra vnode increase disk seek time

Tags: cassandra-2.0

Cassandra 1.2 add new feature virtual node. Devide one physical node into multiple virtual nodes. Does increase disk seek time. Because different virtual nodes have different commit logs. When write into different commit logs, it increases disk seek time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual nodes do not have individual commit logs. There is only one commit log for each physical node.

Comment: I'm with you. Do you have any link to specify that?

Comment: I think I misunderstood vnodes.

Answer (score 1):

Commit log writes are sequential and does not do a disk seek to write the data.

Comment: cassandra don't do a disk seek because it always append, but if one node have multi-vnodes(default 256), it needs to append on different commit logs. It would cost  disk seek time